# Vertically aligned indicators Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By default, indicators are aligned horizontally at the bottom, respectively,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

What is the best way to align the the indicators vertically, so that the indicators are always evenly distributed among the height of the image used within the carousel, with equal space to each indicator? I noticed that the height of the element with id `carousel-example-generic` changes based on the image used within the carousel due to a css property (which probably is at default) `height: auto;`.

Should I use a formula that looks something like:

Height of element with an id of `carousel-example-generic` / amount of indicators = height of indicator?

Should I use JavaScript in order to achieve what I ask here?

I want to achieve something like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpusdvd4/), but I do not want to use a fixed height number for my indicators, I want them to always use the full space they can use within the carousel.

**Edit:** My guess is that the height of the indicators should be calculated with a formula which I show in the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkhy9fmk/).

Answer (score 0):

First You Remove or comment Left and right controls

```
.carousel-indicators li{
display: block;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

.carousel-indicators li display as 'inline-block' is change the 'block' Indicators show vertically

```
.carousel-indicators .active {
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 background-color: #fff;
}
```

Give space for Indicators so, set margin-bottom is 10px and active class also

```
.carousel-indicators{
 height: 350px;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 float: none;
 }
```

Indicators show the the middle in height set for your image size(slider)

Comment: But now the indicators only have a height of 10 pixels. I want them to be as high as possible they can be within the carousel, while being above (or under) each other, while fitting within the height of the carousel (which is only available after using a (e.g. placeholder) image. The whole control would be (in this example) `2 * 10px + 1 * 12px = 32px`, but what if the image height is higher than 32px? I still want them to fit nicely within. I hope you understand what I ask here.

Comment: you increase height as well as width that will not affect the image

Comment: Wouldn't increasing height of the indicators mean they will stretch beyond the bottom of the carousel when the height of an image is smaller than the total amount of indicators times their height, once the carousel goes to one such image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to achieve the result.

You can read the height of the carousel and divide for the `li` element numbers.

```
  var carouselHeight = $("#carousel-example-generic").css("height");
  var elements = $("#carousel-example-generic li").length;
  var indicatorHeight = Math.floor(Number(carouselHeight.replace("px", "")) / elements);

  $("#carousel-example-generic .carousel-indicators li").css("height", indicatorHeight + "px");
```

I have made a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fp1nfcbe/)

Comment: I think your answer is close to what I want to achieve, however we speak of a resize here, when the carousel goes to another image, with a different height, the height of the carousel might change. I suppose adding a resize jquery function here? I will try to add it myself and see how it will turn out and add it to your answer if I get it to work.

Comment: Somehow I cannot get the `.resize()` to work: https://jsfiddle.net/fp1nfcbe/4/ and where it now says `alert(...)` it should set the variabes again and adjust height aswell again.

Comment: See if this lib can help you [css-element-queries](http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/)